# MYSQL get max. values from a specific date

Tags: mysql, date, max

I have a table with multi-year data of temperature measurement.

Looking for the highest measured temperatures including the date of recording from the current year only.

Tried following:

```
SELECT timestamp, temperature AS max_temp
FROM table
WHERE
temperature = (SELECT max(temperature) FROM table
            WHERE timestamp >= '2023-01-01');
```

But now records from complete table are returned with higest measured temperature in 2023.

Who has the right way to go?

Comment: The outer query only filters on the temperature, not on the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Year() function to extract the year portion of the timestamp:
So, the modified query would be :

SELECT timestamp, temperature AS max_temp
FROM table
WHERE
temperature = (SELECT max(temperature) FROM table
WHERE Year(timestamp) = YEAR(CURDATE()));

Hope it works!

Comment: Has same output as the script I tried.

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem:

```
SELECT timestamp,temperature 
FROM tableName 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id 
             FROM tableName 
             WHERE temperature IN (SELECT MAX(temperature) 
                                    FROM tableName 
                                    WHERE LEFT(timestamp,4)='2023')) 
     AND LEFT(timestamp,4)='2023';
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

```
SELECT timestamp, temperature AS max_temp
FROM table
WHERE 
timestamp >= '2023-01-01'
AND
temperature = (SELECT max(temperature) FROM table
            WHERE timestamp >= '2023-01-01');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).